# npm ERR! Missing script: "start" in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular

I create angular project in vc code. I make my project but when I try write `npm start`, I get error:

> npm ERR! Missing script: "start" in angular project".

I checked my `package.json` in project I find follow string:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

Also in project I have folder `node_modules` and `package.json` in it. In this file miss any strings. What I do wrong? Help me, please to fix this problem.

Comment: If the package json contains a `start` script and you get the above error when you try to run `npm start`  your CLI is most certainly not located in the correct folder ...

Comment: Possibly you ran the command from the wrong location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the 'run' word.

Try 'npm run start' or 'ng serve'

Answer (score 0):

Try this command on terminal `npx ng serve`.